# Which guarantees do Scala's singletons have regarding serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, scala, singleton, language-design

Is it safe by default, like Java's single-element-enum pattern or is it e. g. necessary to define `readResolve` or similar methods somewhere to prevent accidental or malicious breakage of the singleton contract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is safe by default:

```
object Singleton extends Serializable
// with Scala 2.8: @serializable object Singleton

import java.io._

val out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("singleton"))
out.writeObject(Singleton)
out.close

val in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("singleton"))
val obj = in.readObject
in.close

obj == Singleton // should print true
```

When you compile the object with scalac and decompile it (for example with JAD) you will get following Java-file:

```
public final class Singleton$ implements Serializable, ScalaObject
{
    public Object readResolve()
    {
        return MODULE$;
    }

    private Singleton$()
    {
    }

    public static final Singleton$ MODULE$ = new Singleton$1();
}
```

Comment: Why is `Singleton` not serializable by default?

Comment: @soc - that question is no different to asking why all types aren't serializable by default - there's a Java question to that effect [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441196/why-java-needs-serializable-interface).

Comment: I disagree. There is basically only one (in 99,5% of the use cases) sensible implementation for serializing the singleton pattern, which is easily overridable if necessary. I just wonder if those 140 bytes saved are _that_ important that it is allowed by default to break the singleton contract.