# Why not serialize it?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Java needs Serializable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441196/why-java-needs-serializable-interface)

What are the negative consequences to serialize an object? There must be some place or Sun all serializable objects. The Serializable interface need not even exist.

Comment: I think it was just coincidence

Comment: Chapter 11 of Joshua Bloch's Effective Java (2nd ed.) is a good read if you want to understand some of the pitfalls and attack vectors that exist for serialized objects. He describes some solid techniques to try and mitigate said problems.

Comment: I liked the proposal, when I have free time I'll try to remember

Answer (score 1):

Some objects can not be safely serialized without extra code, for example if they have an open socket. If you serialize and deserialize the object, the socket will not magically have opened again.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization provides a second means (after the constructors) to instantiate objects. If you have created a singleton class, this can result in more than one object existing when you don't expect it.