# Java: Which classes have to implement Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

I am currently trying to learn and understand how to store data from user input as a file.

Currently, I have the classes "movies" and "series" and the class "MediaLibrary".

Now's the question: Which classes have to implement Serializable?

Do I only have to implement it at MediaLibrary (since I store objects from the other classes in ArrayList's) or do the other classes need Serializable too?

Thanks for your help.

LevKaz

EDIT 1: **What makes my question unique from the possible duplicate?**
In the possible duplicate the guy asked, *why not all objects are serializable*, since he doesn't wanted to write it in every single class. I wanted to know (and understand) if it would be enough to serialize one class which is holding other objects, or if all objects have to implement the serializable interface.

Hopefully I showed up the difference of my question to the one I got suggested by Ali Seyedi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Java needs Serializable interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441196/why-java-needs-serializable-interface)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to work by just writing `implements Serializable`, then all of the classes will need to be `Serializable`, because otherwise an exception will be thrown when attempting to serialize the `ArrayList`.

You *could* avoid making `movies` and `series` `Serializable` by writing `writeObject` in such a way that instead of writing `movies` and `series` objects to the `ObjectOutputStream`, you write their fields directly. However, you should not adopt such an approach unless you have *very* good reason to do so.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad I could help.